# Why callback function is not working in wp_head hook?

Tags: hooks, wp-head

I have two versions of the simplest function that hooked to the `wp_head` action.

One is working, andother one is not.

Can someone explain?

```
// Works !
function custom_description() {
     ?>
         <meta name="description" content="cococo" />
     <?php  
}

// Does not work
/*
function custom_description() {   
    return  '<meta name="description" content="cococo" />';
}
*/

add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_description' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found answer i do not need to return value, i must echo it.
So my function should look like:

```
function custom_description(){   
    echo  '<meta name="description" content="cococo" />';
 }
```

This works  !

Answer (score 1):

You can easily recognize where you're supposed to `return` a value, and where you're supposed to do an action (like `echo` or some other action).

Although, internally they are very similar, but:

1. Any hook that's called a filter hook, and used with `add_filter` function, expects a `return`.
2. On the other hand, any hook that's called an action hook, and used with `add_action` function, doesn't expect a `return` and instead expects an action (like `echo` or something else).

---

Now, in your code, since [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) is an action hook:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_description' );
```

you're supposed to do an action like `echo`, instead of `return`.

---

You'll get more info. from the following documents:

1. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/#actions-vs-filters
2. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/
3. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/